# Centering a div in css using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div vertically using flexbox but `align-items:center;` only changes the contents inside the div. I tried adding `height:100%` but still the same. what should I add/change in the code?

```css
body {
  background: url(images/pattern-background-mobile.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hero">
      </div>

      <h1 class="title">Order Summary</h1>
      <p>You can now listen to millions of songs, audiobooks, and podcasts on any device anywhere you like!
      </p>

      <div class="container">
        <h4>Annual Plan</h4>
        <p>$59.99/year</p>
        <a href="#">Change</a>
      </div>

      <button>Proceed to Payment</button>
      <a href="#">Cancel Order</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to bring the whole thing? Actually I don't clearly understand your question. Still providing a solution. I guess it will help you.

```css
body {
  background: url(images/pattern-background-mobile.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 80%;
}

.main{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="main">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="hero">
            </div>

            <h1 class="title">Order Summary</h1>
            <p>You can now listen to millions of songs, audiobooks, and podcasts on any 
              device anywhere you like!
            </p>

            <div class="container">
              <h4>Annual Plan</h4>
              <p>$59.99/year</p>
              <a href="#">Change</a>
            </div>

            <button>Proceed to Payment</button>
            <a href="#">Cancel Order</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help. You have to add the flex classes to the container that surrounds the elements you want to center.

```css
body {
    background: url(images/pattern-background-mobile.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

main { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 10%;
}

.container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2% 5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hero">
      </div>

      <h1 class="title">Order Summary</h1>
      <p>You can now listen to millions of songs, audiobooks, and podcasts on any 
        device anywhere you like!
      </p>

      <div class="container">
        <h4>Annual Plan</h4>
        <p>$59.99/year</p>
        <a href="#">Change</a>
      </div>

      <button>Proceed to Payment</button>
      <a href="#">Cancel Order</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```